# V3 API equivalent of "category: 'Music'" in V2 API?

Tags: youtube-api, freebase, youtube-data-api

I'm converting an existing application from YouTube's V2 API to their V3 API. The V2 API supported a concept of 'Categories', https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_category_keyword_browsing, which I have to assume is usurped by freebase topic IDs.

In the V2 API I would pass in a parameter such as:

```
category: 'Music'
```

which would have the effect of mostly limiting results to just music.

I'm not overly familiar with the freebase system. Looking into it, it seems that it provides very specific topic IDs and not broad categories such as "music."

I'm left wondering how to preserve this functionality under the V3 API. I would like to, as best possible, only receive "music" results from my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freebase has topics for broad things like Music (/m/04rlf) as well as specific genres (e.g. Rock Music /m/06by7).  I'm not sure how the YouTube tagging is focused, but you should be able to pick a topic at the right level for application.